# Perl - Remove trailing zeroes without exponential value

Tags: perl

I am trying to remove trailing zeroes from decimal numbers.

For eg: If the input number is 0.0002340000, I would like the output to be 0.000234

I am using `sprintf("%g",$number)`, but that works for the most part, except sometimes it converts the number into an exponential value with E-. How can I have it only display as a full decimal number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers don't have trailing zeroes. Trailing zeroes can only occur once you represent the number in decimal, a string. So the first step is to convert the number to a string if it's not already.

```
my $s = sprintf("%.10f", $n);
```

(The solution is suppose to work with the OP's inputs, and his inputs appear to have 10 decimal places. If you want more digits to appear, use the number of decimal places you want to appear instead of 10. I thought this was obvious. If you want to be ridiculous like @asjo, use 324 decimal places for the doubles if you want to make sure not to lose any precision you didn't already lose.)

Then you can delete the trailing zeroes.

```
$s =~ s/0+\z// if $s =~ /\./;
$s =~ s/\.\z//;
```

or

```
$s =~ s/\..*?\K0+\z//;
$s =~ s/\.\z//;
```

or

```
$s =~ s/\.(?:|.*[^0]\K)0*\z//;
```

Comment: @ikegami, surely the proposed solution is supposed to work for a number such as the one I suggested? Add a trailing zero to it, if you want to, the question remains (hint: %.10f rounds off!)

Comment: @ikegami, I would assume that there could be _any_ number of digits before and after the decimal point. So what would you propose to change 10 to?

Comment: @ikegami, what makes you assume there there could not be 11 digits after the decimal point? The question gives an example, it doesn't say anything about the number of digits.

Comment: The problem is that the number of decimal points can be arbitrary, but your solution requires a fixed amount. It will (probably) work with exaggerated numbers, such as `%.100f`.

Comment: You get funny artifacts of floating point numbers if you try with wide formats; try `say sprintf "%0.60f", 0.00000000001;'

Comment: @ikegami, there no indication of any upper limit in the question, so I assume there is none.

Comment: @ikegami, I guess that is very much in the eye of the beholder. I read much less into the example than you do, obviously.

Comment: @asjo, I have updated my answer to address your concerns (and removed the now-redundant messages).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid scientific notation for numbers use the format conversion `%f` instead of `%g`.

Comment: When I try using %f it rounds the number upto 6 decimal places. I have cases where there may be upto 12 decimal places and I want to preserve all the decimal places when they are present

Comment: Then you need to now how wide a format to specify! This question is trickier than it seems, it seems.

Comment: @user333746 The default precision for `%f` is 6 digits to the right of the decimal point. You can specify n-digit precision with `%.nf` (e.g. `%.10f` will give 10 digits precision). You can also specify the precision with an extra argument to sprintf like this: `sprintf("%.*f", $precision, $value)`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is easier than you might think.

Instead of using `%g` use `%f` and it will result in the behavior you are looking for. `%f` will always output your floating decimal in "*fixed decimal notation*".

---

#### What does the documentation say about `%g` vs `%f`?

As you may notice in the below table `%g` will result in either the same as `%f` **or** `%e` (when appropriate).

Ff you'd want to force the use of *fixed decimal notation* use the appropriate format identifier, which in this case is `%f`.

[**sprintf - perldoc.perl.org**](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html)

```
   %%    a percent sign
   %c    a character with the given number
   %s    a string
   %d    a signed integer, in decimal
   %u    an unsigned integer, in decimal
   %o    an unsigned integer, in octal
   %x    an unsigned integer, in hexadecimal
   %e    a floating-point number, in scientific notation
   %f    a floating-point number, in fixed decimal notation
   %g    a floating-point number, in %e or %f notation
```

---

#### What about TIMTOWTDI; aren't we writing perl?

Yes, as always there are more than one ways of doing it.

If you'd just like to trim the trailing decimal-point zeros from a **string** you could use a regular expression such as the below.

```
$number =  "123000.321000";
$number =~ s/(\.\d+?)0+$/$1/;

$number # is now "12300.321"
```

Remember that floating point values in perl doesn't have trailing decimals, unless you are dealing with a string. With that said; a string is not a number, even though it can explicitly and implicitly be converted to one.

Comment: That removes all decimal places if there's a trailing zero.

Comment: @ikegami I edited my post 3 minutes ago, according to SO that's 1 minute before you made your comment. could you clarify what you are referring to?

Comment: I guess I loaded the page at least one minute before replying. Your updated solution can leave a trailing ".", which will technically within the spec, is probably undesired.

Answer (score 1):

A lazy way could be simply: `$number=~s/0+$//` (substitute trailing zeroes by nothing).

Comment: The above regular expression will **not** result in correct behavior if the floating point is something as `123000.0`! See [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8674583/1090079) for the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Well, "123000." arguably has all trailing zeroes removed :-) The real problem is if the variable is a number rather than a string.

Comment: OP wanted to trim all trailing zeros from decimal numbers, which "arguably" implies that only zeros after the decimal point should be removed. A string such as "123000" doesn't have any trailing *decimal* zeros, and your regular expression will handle it in an incorrect manner. Though we could argue whether a provided solution should be specific for handling decimal numbers (as strings) and when using it on an integer value it's the developers fault if it results in unexpected behavior. **;-)**

Comment: Your example was "123000.0" which is problemless. You are right that if there is no decimal point in the decimal number, then it wont work.

Comment: Oh, my bad - I wrote the example too fast, thanks for correcting me regarding the matter.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably to multiply by 1.

Original:

```perl
my $num = sprintf("%.10f", 0.000234000001234);
print($num);

#output
0.0002340000
```

With multiplying:

```perl
my $num = sprintf("%.10f", 0.000234000001234) * 1;
print($num);

#output
0.000234
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the `%g` format is to use a fixed point notation when it is reasonable and to use exponential notation when fixed point is not reasonable.  So, you need to know the range of values you'll be dealing with.

Clearly, you could write a regular expression to post-process the string from `sprintf()`, removing the trailing zeroes:

```
my $str = sprintf("%g", $number);
$str =~ s/0+$//;
```

If you always want a fixed point number, use '`%f`', possibly with number of decimal places that you want; you might still need to remove trailing zeroes.  If you always want exponential notation, use '`%e`'.

Comment: There won't be any trailing zeroes with that if you format with `%g` because it will be presented in exponential notation; if you use plain `%f`, you will get all zeroes after the decimal point because the default precision is 6 (and the regex will strip all the zeroes off after the decimal point, leaving `0.`; a fuller regex might well remove the decimal point too: `s/\.?0+$//`).  Yes, I think I know what will happen.  The question is: what does the questioner want to happen? Since we've not been told about the range of values to be formatted, we can't tell exactly what's best.

Comment: The question is about _avoiding_ exponentional notation, so %g wont  work for small numbers, which is why I asked.

Comment: So that's why I said '%g' uses fixed or exponential and if you only want fixed, used '%f'...so...I'm not sure what you're complaint is?  If you would answer differently, please go ahead and do so.

Answer (score 0):

**An easy way:**

You could cheat a little. Add 1 to avoid the number breaking into scientific notation. Then manipulate the number as a string (thereby making perl convert it into a string).

```
$n++; 
$n =~ s/^(\d+)(?=\.)/$1 - 1/e;
print $n;
```

---

**A "proper" way:**

For a more "proper" solution, counting the number of decimal places to use with `%f` would be optimal. It turned out getting the correct number of decimal points is trickier than one would think. Here's an attempt:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my $n = 0.000000234;
say    "Original: $n";
my $l = getlen($n);
printf "New     : %.${l}f\n", $n;

sub getlen {
    my $num = shift;
    my $dec = 0;
    return 0 unless $num;    # no 0 values allowed
    return 0 if $num >= 1;   # values above 1 don't need this computation
    while ($num < 1) {
        $num *= 10;
        $dec++;
    }
    $num =~ s/\d+\.?//;     # must have \.? to accommodate e.g. 0.01
    $dec += length $num;
    return $dec;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Original: 2.34e-007
New     : 0.000000234
```

Answer (score 0):

The value can have trailing zeroes only if it is a string.
You can add 0 to it. It will be coverted to a numerical value, not showing any trailing zeroes.