# Using perl bigint in ranges

Tags: perl, bigint

When I iterate through some integer range and try to use $_ value as bigint, it behaves like regular number instead. So, the following code prints 
`100000000000000000000
1e+20` 
when I expect to see `100000000000000000000 100000000000000000000`.

```perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use bigint;

for my $b(10) {
    for my $c(20) {
        print $b**$c, "\n";
    }
}

for my $b(10..10) {
    for my $c(20..20) {
        print $b**$c, "\n";
    }
}
```

How can I make this code behave in a correct way? I do know about Math::BigInt, but I wonder if there is a solution without it.

Comment: The code you provided will output one number per line, not two. And your code does not use `$_` at all. Please edit your code or your question so that your code demonstrates what you are talking about in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason but the below link will help you to print exact value. Get the control string length and print the value.

[Perl - Remove trailing zeroes without exponential value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674554/perl-remove-trailing-zeroes-without-exponential-value)

Comment: Thanks for your link, but that is not exactly what I want. The value which is displayed as `1e+20` is a floating point number with finite precision, but not an exact integer. And I want to get the exact value but not to print it in another way.